# Understanding splitting list item to variable python code

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python code I know where is it used but want to know its meaning so that I can use it for my bigger python projects This is my python code

```
var_list = [100,2025]
slice1,slice2 = (var_list + [None] *2)[:2]
print(slice1,slice2)
```

if you need more information you can take it from the comments

Comment: In general, on stackoverflow we ask specific questions about specific programming problems. Your question is more about the fact that you need to rewrite a tutorial or read more about the [language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood your question, but this is what the code is doing:

var_list is a list with two elements `[100, 2025]`.

slice1 and slice2 are being defined as `(var_list + [None]*2)[:2]`. This expression adds the var_list to a new list of 2 None objects (`[None] * 2 == [None, None]`). The result of this expression (`(var_list + [None] *2)`) is the addition of these 2 lists, which is: `[100, 2025, None, None]`

Then the last part (`[:2]`) is just slicing the first 2 elements of this resulting list and assigning it to the variables. And since, in this case, the first 2 items are the var_list itself, it will assign the first element to slice1 and the second to slice2.